# WCF Service returns 'null'

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am currently developing a small WCF service to do some email parsing
(note: very new to WCF development). I am having to integrate this with some quite old VB.Net code which already uses an ASMX web service to carry out a similar operation. My test service is very simple at the moment, I just wanted to make sure my service was running and could pass back the correct information.
(Another note: My service is written in C# because I'm more comfortable with it than VB.Net)

```
public struct WrapperResults
    {
        public bool Success;
        public string ErrorMessage;
    }

    public class MQWrapper : IService1
    {
        public WrapperResults CallWrapper(string AppName, string Password, string ConfigXML)
        {
            WrapperResults results = new WrapperResults();

            results.ErrorMessage = "test";
            results.Success = true;

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Now when this service gets called, I can step into this function and see 'results.ErrorMessage' and 'results.Success' getting set properly, but when the service returns the values to the VB code, the values are just 'Nothing' and 'False' respectively.

So I used Fiddler to check the actual XML responses from both the ASMX Service (which I know works) and the new WCF Service and it seems the responses differ very slightly.

ASMX Service Response (Working)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CallWrapperResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CallWrapperResult>
        <Success>true</Success>
        <ErrorMessage>test</ErrorMessage>
      </CallWrapperResult>
    </CallWrapperResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

WCF Service Response (Not working)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <CallWrapperResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CallWrapperResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TFXEmailProcessor" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ErrorMessage>test</a:ErrorMessage>
        <a:Success>true</a:Success>
      </CallWrapperResult>
    </CallWrapperResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now I'm not sure if these differences would have any effect on the program but is there a way to make the WCF Service respond with the same XML format of the ASMX service?

Comment: Try decorating WrapperResults with `[DataContract(Namespace="")]`

Comment: @OrelEraki That seems to make the WCF Service Response just blank. It has the `CallWrapperResult` node but doesn't have either `ErrorMessage` or `Success` nodes.

I assume you meant to put that line above the WrapperResults struct?